# Evaluating limits: one or two sided?

Tags: limits

When evaluating a limit expression, how do we know whether to evaluate the Right hand limit and left hand limit separately OR evaluate the "two-sided-limit"?

Comment: This is the general rule, but I haven't the time to flesh it out into an answer right now: if both sides makes sense, you _should_ evaluate both sides. If only one side makes sense, then only evaluate that side.

Comment: If the arrow does not have a plus or minus sign with it, it is assumed to be a two sided limit

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$$

In general, when a direction is not specified, we look to evaluate the limit as a two-sided limit *if* the function is defined on either side. The above limit exists if both one-sided limits exist and if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f(x)$.

However, as mentioned earlier, we sometimes run into limits that cannot be evaluated from both sides. Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. The domain of this function is $x \in [0,\infty)$. Now consider

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sqrt{x}$$

Here it doesn't even make sense to take a two sided limit. The function isn't defined for $x<0$. So this limit would be tacitly considered as

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \sqrt{x}$$

### $\\$

*Word of caution for AP Calculus students: See imranfat's comment below. I do not know how the AP test defines their limit notation, but the one in my answer is generally used practice.*

Comment: This is a good answer, +1. Note that $x$ is allowed to approach $a$ only through domain points of $f$ (as you observed), so it is even possible to have a 2-sided limit if the domain of $f$ is something like $\{\pm\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: Thanks @MPW. I wanted to address something along those lines, but was at a lack of words. Well said!

Comment: @zahbaz You got to be VERY careful with that tacitly consideration. On the AP exam in a multiple choice question, zero as an answer would be considered incorrect. The correct answer is then that the limit does not exist.This is the better way of teaching students limit notation. That brings the question what the point of such a question would be other than testing the students on the limit notation.

Comment: @imranfat Interesting. I'll make an edit to warn AP calculus students.